# How to refresh contact form on the same page HTML PHP JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

Really struggling with this one, didn't think a simple form would be this complicated. I'm a newbie when it comes to the back-end.

I have 3 fields; name, email, and message. On submit, I just want a simple "thank you" message inside the form box. I do not want to send to another page or refresh to the top of the current page. I want the form to refresh with the 'thank you' message, ideally with the message disappearing after a few seconds.

After trying a few different methods I am almost there with JS, using an event listener to show the "thank you" message after clicking submit.

However, now the contact form doesn't refresh on submit and the data that was inputted still shows on the form along with the thank you message. How do you get the form to refresh on submit?

I have always used WordPress, and contact forms seemed so simple. I have spent hours on this so far.

HTML

```html
<div class="form-box">
<p id="thank-you-message">
    Thank you for your message. We will be in touch with you very soon.
</p>
<form method="POST" action="contact-form.php" >
    <div class="form-control">
        <input class="text-box" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name*" required>
        <input class="text-box" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email Adress*" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Project Details" required></textarea>
        <button class="send" name="submit" type="submit">SEND</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP

```php
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !='') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST ['email'];
    $message = $_POST ['message'];

    $email_from = 'website.com';

    $email_subject = "New Form Submission";
    
    $email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
                    "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                        "User Message: $message.\n";

    $to = "contact@email.com";

    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    header("Location: index.html");

    }

    ?>
```

JS

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const thankYouMessage = document.querySelector('#thank-you-message');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  thankYouMessage.classList.add('show');
  setTimeout(() => form.submit(), 2000);
});
```

---

@James Bakker

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="contact-form.php" >
<?php echo $successMessage ?>
<div class="form-control">
                            <input type="hidden" name="valid" value="false">
                            <input class="text-box" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name*" required>
                            <input class="text-box" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email Adress*" required>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Project Details" required></textarea>
                            <button class="send" name="button" type="submit">SEND</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

JS

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  form.valid.value = 'true';
    consultForm.submit();
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
    
    $successMessage == '';
    if($_POST['valid'] == 'true'){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST ['email'];
    $message = $_POST ['message'];

    $email_from = 'website.com';

    $email_subject = "New Form Submission";
    
    $email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
                    "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
                        "User Message: $message.\n";

    $to = "contact@email.com";

    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";

    $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

    $header("Location: index.html");
    
    $success = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); 
   
   if ($success){
        $successMessage = 'Your Message was sent!';
    } else {
   $successMessage = 'There was a problem, message was not sent';
        
    }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Using an action with <form> will always refresh, unfortunately. Consider using fetch() with js to make the request on a button click.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this a client-side problem (where the browser does not behave as expected), or a server-side problem (where the requests sent by the browser are handled faulty)?

Comment: @TomRoman It doesn't refresh, the form stays the same with the data still inside. I want the form to refresh and show my 'thank you' message after clicking send.

Comment: @NicoHaase Sorry, not sure if I understand. It's my own website, I am just trying to get the contact form to function how I want.

Comment: And what **exactly** have you tried to check for whatever is not working? What does "he contact form doesn't refresh on submit" mean, and what have you tried to make that work?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have tried a few different methods from old questions posted here on stackoverflow. The backend logic posted in other areas makes sense, but writing up the code is what is giving me a hard time.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use `fetch` or regular `XMLHttpRequest` you can use the callback to manipulate the DOM after the data has been sent to the backend PHP script.

The PHP script that handles the request will no longer require the `header('Location: index.html');` - instead you could echo/return a message to be used by the ajax callback.

The below is not tested as such

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    let form=document.querySelector('form');
    
    form.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
    
        e.preventDefault();
        
        fetch( 'contact-form.php' , { method:'post', body:( new FormData( e.target.parentNode.parentNode ) ) } )
            .then( r=>r.text() )
            .then( data=>{
            
                //show the message
                document.querySelector('#thank-you-message').classList.add('show');
                

                //iterate through form elements and set the value to empty string if it is not a button
                for( i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++ ){
                    let el=form.elements[i]
                    if( el.type!='button' )el.value='';
                }
                
                // remove the button
                e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
            })
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="form-box">
    <p id="thank-you-message">
        Thank you for your message. We will be in touch with you very soon.
      </p>
    <form method="POST" action="contact-form.php" >
        <div class="form-control">
            <input class="text-box" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name*" required>
            <input class="text-box" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email Adress*" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Project Details" required></textarea>
            <button class="send" name="submit" type="submit">SEND</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Decided to go ahead with your suggestion with a couple tweaks and it's working the closest to how I would like. Only issue now is that it is that the JS doesn't validated the form before sending, so I will spend some time trying to figure that out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:  You need to change the `name` attribute of your submit button to something other than submit, then you will be able to call `form.submit()` using your JS.

Currently your page works as such:

1. User enters info and clicks submit
2. Your JS captures the event and
   prevents default action
3. You display the thank you message and then
   submit() the form.

The problems with this approach are:

1. The thank you message is displayed before the actual message is sent.
2. There is no form validation
3. The message is only displayed for 2 seconds, and only before the actual email is sent.

A better approach is:

1. User fills out form and clicks submit
2. JS captures the event, prevents default, validates all of the data, and if everything is valid if submits the form, POSTing the form values to the current page, this will reload the page and clear the form fields.
3. Your PHP script will take the POSTed variables, send the email, and display your thank you message on the page.

The advantages are:

1. You don't display a message until the email is actually sent
2. You are making sure the form has valid entries
3. Your message is displayed after refresh and wont disappear after 2 seconds

Heres how, (code isn't tested):

Make a hidden input in your form with the name 'valid':

```
<input type="hidden" name="valid" value="false">
```

Once the your JS has validated the inputs you would set this to true and submit() the form.  This will post the variable to your PHP along with the rest of the form values.

```
form.valid.value = 'true';
consultForm.submit();
```

in your php you write an if statement:

```
$successMessage == '';
create empty variable success message than we will assign a message if a form submission is detected.
if($_POST['valid] == 'true'){ //keep in mind we are passing a string 
   not an actual boolean
   //insert your php email script here
   $success = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers); 
   //assigning return value of mail() to variable named success
   
   if($success){
        $successMessage = 'Your Message was sent!'
   } else {
   $successMessage = 'There was a problem, message was not sent'
}
```

you can then echo $successMessage anywhere in your HTML.

```
<?php echo $successMessage ?>
```

when the page is initially loaded, before the form submit, $successMessage will be an empty string, so echo $successMessage will have no affect on the page.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed breakdown. It makes perfect sense, but having difficulty making the code work.

Please see the code at the bottom of the original message for what I have so far from your message. Would appreciate it if you could have a look? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Happy to help.  You copied “consultForm.submit();” but you need to rename consult form to the name of your form.  In your case just ‘form’.  That should take care of the form submit.  If that doesn’t fix it check for other errors.  FYI:  You can see errors in your JavaScript using the log in your browsers developer tools.  It’s very helpful for debugging.  In your case it would have told you that ‘consultForm’ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks James. You are right, should've checked the console. I think I have fixed the JS, because it sends the request to my contact-form.php page now. However, now I just get a blank page on mysite.com/contact-form.php, with the message "This page isn’t working mysite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500". There may be an error with my php above? Thank you again.

Comment: Is the error actually saying ‘mysite.com’?  Did you copy and paste something and forget to change mysite.com to your actual site?